# What does indentation mean in gdb dump?

Tags: gdb, indentation

```
0x80002bc <__execve>:   pushl  %ebp
0x80002bd <__execve+1>: movl   %esp,%ebp
0x80002bf <__execve+3>: pushl  %ebx
0x80002c0 <__execve+4>: movl   $0xb,%eax
0x80002c5 <__execve+9>: movl   0x8(%ebp),%ebx
0x80002c8 <__execve+12>:        movl   0xc(%ebp),%ecx
0x80002cb <__execve+15>:        movl   0x10(%ebp),%edx
```

The last 2 lines are indented,what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a "bug". There's a single tab behind the colon. When the offset reaches two digits (+12) this tab moves 8 spaces further.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's a simple case of a `TAB` char.

Note that the first two lines are aligned and only when the colon breaks the `TAB` barrier the other lines are indented.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has no meaning at all. The indentation seems to be caused by tab-padding (every 8th character).